# Multiple pattern matching

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input file with columns seperated by | as follows.

```
[3yu23yuoi]|$name
!$fjkdjl|[kkklkl]
$hjhj|$mmkj
```

I want the output as

```
0          $name
!$fjkdjl     0
$hjhj      $mmkj
```

Whenever the string begins with $ or !$ or "any", i want it to get printed as such else 0.
I have tried the following command.It prints verything same as input file only.

```
awk -F="|" '{if (($1 ~ /^.*\$/) || ($1 ~ /^.*\!$/) || ($1 ~ /^any/)) {print $1} else if ($1 ~ /^\[.*/){print "0"} else if (($2 ~ /^.*\$/) || ($2 ~ /^.*\!$/) || ($2 ~ /^any/)) {print $2} else if($2 ~ /^\[.*/){print "0"}}' input > output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F\| '{$1=$1;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/^(\$|!\$|any)/) $i=0}1' file
0 $name
!$fjkdjl 0
$hjhj $mmkj
```

If data does not start with `$` `!$` or `any`, set it to `0`

Or if you like tab as separator:

```
awk -F\| '{$1=$1;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/^(\$|!\$|^any)/) $i=0}1' OFS="\t" file
0       $name
!$fjkdjl        0
$hjhj   $mmkj
```

`$1=$1` make sure all line have same output, even if no data is changed.